Why does my Angular 9 sort routine work great when using Google Chrome (Ch131) browser, but works poorly (gets Wait msg) when using MS Edge (Ch131)?
I'm still on Windows 10 - can't upgrade to Windows 11 on my laptop due to a specific processor/chip version that is not compatible with Windows 11.  I have all Windows 10 updates installed.  I have gone through Settings and Repaired/Modified my MS Edge install to latest version, so all that should be good.
My Component code is:
 columnSort(colName: string): void {
   if (this.sortedAsc) {   // sorts in ascending order
     this.sortedAsc = false;
     this.members =
       this.members.sort((m1, m2) => {
         return m1[colName].toLowerCase() < m2[colName].toLowerCase() ? -1 :
           (m1[colName].toLowerCase() > m2[colName].toLowerCase() ? 1 : 0);
       });
   } else {  // sorts in descending order
     this.sortedAsc = true;
     this.members =
       this.members.sort((m1, m2) => {
         return m1[colName].toLowerCase() > m2[colName].toLowerCase() ? -1 :
           (m1[colName].toLowerCase() < m2[colName].toLowerCase() ? 1 : 0);
       });
}

}
HTML Template Code:
  <th class="freezecol3 fixed-header" (click)="columnSort('last_Name')">Last Name &uarr;&darr;</th>
  <th class="freezecol4 fixed-header" (click)="columnSort('first_Name')">First Name &uarr;&darr;</th>

F12 Developer Tools in Edge and Chrome show Request headers like:
  sec-ch-ua: "Microsoft Edge";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24"
  sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
  sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
  sec-fetch-dest: empty
  sec-fetch-mode: cors
  sec-fetch-site: same-origin
  user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0

Edge browser gets "This page isn't responding" message (after 10 to 15 seconds) when column is clicked for sorting.  When I click "Wait", the sort takes about 30 seconds in MS Edge.  In Chrome & Safari, there is no error condition, and the sort is complete in 2 to 3 seconds.


Is this.members massive and being dumped into the template?

@Carcigenicate No, the SQL table contains 616 data rows, each with 37 fields. About 76K bytes total. All Requested member info is added into the this.members array from the HTTP Response and the displayed grid is in ascending order by last name - before anyone can click a column heading to sort otherwise. I wouldn't call it massive, but the behavior does look like it is taking a long time to process in Edge browser, but not having a problem in Google Chrome or Safari browsers. Older versions of Edge had no problem with 550 data rows or less. Maybe I've reached a limit in MS Edge now?

I had to delete and re-Add the  above comment to make a correction.

make a more efficient sort (current one is really imperformant), or just use sortBy from any of the utilities libraries

@Andrei  This sort is formatted basically the same as shown by MS CoPilot for sorting  an Angular 9 Typescript array - except that my version works to sort ascending or descending with 1 click of the mouse, and I convert all strings to lowercase for comparisons.  What would a more efficient sort of the rows of an Angular 9 Typescript array look like?

If you have extensions installed on Microsoft Edge, you can try disabling them for a test. Sometimes extensions can cause hang issues.
Also, you can try toggling a particular setting called Use graphics acceleration when available at edge://settings/system, which has something to do with Edge performance.
